# JQuery autocomplete does not like numbers in this example

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I have a jquery example that works when i enter letters but does not work when i enter numbers:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#box1").autocomplete({
            url: 'test-search3.ashx?s=mrn'
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
 <input type="text" id="box1">
</form>
```

Here is the code for the ashx page:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="test_search" %>
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Text

Public Class test_search : Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
        Dim qString As String = context.Request.QueryString("q")
        Dim typeString As String = context.Request.QueryString("s")
        Dim sqlStr As String = ""

        Try
            Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connString").ConnectionString
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
            If typeString = "mrn" Then               
                sqlStr = "select Pat_ID, Name=LastName + ', ' + FirstName " & _
                " from Patients p Where Active=1 " & _
                " and p.MRN like '" & qString & "%' order by lastname"
            Else
                sqlStr = "select Pat_ID, Name=LastName + ', ' + FirstName " & _
                " from Patients p Where Active=1 " & _
                " and Lower(LastName) like '" & qString & "%' order by lastname"
            End If

            cmd.CommandText = (sqlStr)
            cmd.Connection = conn
            Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
            conn.Open()
            Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            'sb.Append(qString & "/" & typeString).Append(Environment.NewLine)
            While sdr.Read
                sb.Append(sdr("Name") & "|" & sdr("Pat_ID")).Append(Environment.NewLine)
            End While
            conn.Close()
            context.Response.Write(sb.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            context.Response.Write("Error: " & ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: You need to provide more information

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I type letters in the textbox it works but when I type numbers it does not work. I need numbers to work because I will need to search by zip code or employee number soon.

Comment: Try to debug with FireBug - see ajax requests and responses. This is not a question!

Comment: ALso look at the autocomplete plugin you use if it is properly configured (accepted characters etc.). It probably has some documentation. Check your code at the server.

Comment: When I call the ashx directly (as follows test-search3.ashx?s=mrn&q=301) it returns the data. The data looks like this Davis, Tommy|2264.

Comment: Perhaps I should ask if anyone knows of a setting or restriction for jquery autocomplete that only accepts letters and NOT numbers?

Comment: Exploits of a mom: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I realized what I was doing wrong. I was not returning the number in the results so jquery was not matching it. For example instead of returning Davis,Tommy|2264 I should have been doing 2264|Davis,Tommy. I will probably delete this question because I'm new to Jquery and probably did not state the problem clearly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of jquery autocomplete plugins which work fairly well.

This [plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) is a good one.

For other [jQuery Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188442/whats-a-good-ajax-autocomplete-plugin-for-jquery).

Comment: I looked at that one but it did not help. An example that searches for zip codes, or some sort of id number would probably be better.